# Action on a certain class of Fourier functions

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am going through Chapter 4 (Fourier Transforms) of Stein's Complex Analysis text and cannot follow a certain part of Theorem 2.1 which appears as if it should be trivial.

First, for $a>0$, Stein defines a class of functions $\mathcal{F}_a$ such that $f \in \mathcal{F}_a$ if:

1. The function $f$ is holomorphic in the horizontal strip
   $$S_a = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |\text{Im}(z)| < a \}$$
2. There exists a constant $A > 0$ such that
   $$|f(x + iy)| \leq \frac{A}{1+x^2} \quad \text{for all } x \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and } |y| < a.$$

Now here is the theorem itself:

> If $f$ belongs to the class $\mathcal{F}_a$ for some $a > 0$, then
> $|\hat{f}(\xi)| \leq B e^{-2\pi b |\xi|}$ for any $0 \leq b < a$.

To prove this for $0 < b <a$ and the case $\xi > 0$ Stein shifts the contour of integration (the real line) down by $b$, and defines a function $g(z) = f(z)e^{-2\pi i z \xi}$. He shows that as $R$ tends to infinity, the integrals of $g$ over the two vertical sides converge to zero:
$$\Biggl |\int_{-R-ib}^{-R} g(z) dz \Biggr | \leq \int_0^b |f(-R-it)e^{-2\pi i (-R-it)\xi} | dt \\\leq \int_0^b\frac{A}{R^2} e^{-2\pi t \xi}dt$$

Here is the illustration in the text illustrating the contour in question:
[image]

Now I understand the first inequality holds from your basic integral inequalities. The second I am less sure of, though it clearly uses the property of moderate decrease, I am just now sure how, and also how the argument of the exponential changes as well to remove $R$.

Also, how come it suffices to prove the integral over the vertical segments go to zero and that the integral of the interior is 0? Wouldn't we also have to show that the lower of the two horizontal segments also go to 0?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moderate decrease is used to bound
$$
|f(-R-it)|\leq \dfrac{A}{1+R^2} \leq \dfrac{A}{R^2}.
$$
On the other hand, for the exponential we have
$$
|e^{-2\pi i(-R-it)\xi}|= |e^{2\pi iR\xi}||e^{-2\pi t\xi}|= e^{-2\pi t\xi},
$$
where we distributed the $-2\pi i\xi$ term in the exponent, and used that $|e^{i\theta}|=1$ for any $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks that clears up the first part. For the second, why does he ignore proving anything related to the lower of the two horizontal sides?

Comment: @CBBAM: From what you mention in your post (I don't have the book right now), my guess is that he's just saying that the integral over the real line is the same as the "shifted" one (with the right orientation).

Comment: After showing the two verticals tend to 0 as $R \rightarrow \infty$, Stein says "Therefore, by Cauchy's theorem applied to the large rectangle, we find the limit as $R$ tends to infinity that $\hat{f}(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x-ib) e^{-2\pi i)(x-ib)\xi}dx$".  Actually writing this out, it seems since this integral should be 0 (as $f$ is holomorphic), he just rearranges the two integrals to obtain the result.

Comment: @CBBAM: Isn't the right hand side exactly the bottom part of the rectangle?

Comment: I don't believe so unless I'm misunderstanding your comment

Comment: @CBBAM: I'm not sure what the confusion is. If I'm reading this right, Stein wants to write the Fourier transform $\hat{f}(\xi)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\, dx$ in terms of a translate. What the computation is, is saying that in going from one to the other you make an error (the left and right sides of the rectangle) that vanishes in the limit.

Comment: Yes that is in fact what I had thought was the case in one of my earlier comments.